# Youtube API with python, multiple requests

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api

I want to write a code that will take off the likes from my liked videos. I try this with 2 requests. The first is for me to find out the id of the video and the second is to perform the removal. I would like to make this into a for loop but im having trouble with only one video too. This is my first time with APIs so im sure i did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pickle
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = None

# token.pickle stores the user's credentials from previously successful logins
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    print('Loading Credentials From File...')
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        credentials = pickle.load(token)

# If there are no valid credentials available, then either refresh the token or log in.
if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
    if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
        print('Refreshing Access Token...')
        credentials.refresh(Request())
    else:
        print('Fetching New Tokens...')
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret.json',
                                                         scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
                                                                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
                                                                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"])

        flow.run_local_server(port=8080, prompt='consent', authorization_prompt_message='')
        credentials = flow.credentials

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            print('Saving Credentials for Future Use...')
            pickle.dump(credentials, f)

youtube = build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)

request = youtube.videos().list(part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics", myRating="like", maxResults=1).execute()
#print(request)

# Getting title, id and duration of liked video
for item in request["items"]:
    global vid_title
    global vid_id
    global vid_time
    vid_title = item["snippet"]["title"]
    vid_id = item["id"]
    vid_time = item["contentDetails"]["duration"]
    vid_time = vid_time.replace("M", " minute ")
    vid_time = vid_time.replace("S", " second ")
    vid_time = vid_time[2:]
    # print(vid_title)
    #print(vid_id)

request = youtube.videos().rate(id=vid_id, rating="none").execute()

print(vid_title + " was removed from the liked videos")
```

Comment: Is this code an answer to your question? Or are you providing additional information regarding your question? Please make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to make this into a for loop but im having trouble with only one video too

I believe it's due this line:

```
request = youtube.videos().rate(id=vid_id, rating="none").execute()
```

***That line should be inside the `for` loop***.

***Check closely the indentation of your code.***

This is the modified code:

```
# Getting title, id and duration of liked video: 
for item in request["items"]:
    global vid_title
    global vid_id
    global vid_time
    vid_title = item["snippet"]["title"]
    vid_id = item["id"]
    vid_time = item["contentDetails"]["duration"]
    vid_time = vid_time.replace("M", " minute ")
    vid_time = vid_time.replace("S", " second ")
    vid_time = vid_time[2:]

    # Remove the rate of the video: 
    request = youtube.videos().rate(id=vid_id, rating="none").execute()

    # Print the video's title
    print(vid_title + " was removed from the liked videos")
```